# How do i open a webcam frame in OpenCV and a tkinter window at the same time without using any threading in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter, python-multithreading

Someone from here gave me this code that uses threading. This code works fine but what i want is to open the webcam frame and the tkinter at the same time without using threading.

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
import threading

ui = Tk()
ui.state('zoomed')


def video_stream():
  video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
  while True:
    check, frame = video.read()
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
  video.release()
  cv2.destroyAllWindows

th= threading.Thread(target=video_stream) #initialise the thread
th.setDaemon(True)
th.start() #start the thread

ui.mainloop() #Run your UI
```

Comment: tkinter need to run `mainloop()` which block other code - so it makes problem . You could use `root.after(time, function_name)` (instead of `while True`) to run periodicaly function with OpenCV code.

Comment: OpenCV uses PyQt to display image in cv.imshow() - maybe you should use PyQt instead of Tkinter.

Comment: if you need button or label then you can draw rectangle and text on frame with OpenCV and simulate button/label.

Comment: Interesting..  Never knew opencv used pyqt.